# Tagging system for job platform

Tags: java, mysql, tags

I'm building a job platform with Java Spring (RESTful API).
I would like to have tags like stackoverflow has it (so that a candidate can enter his skills) or https://jobspotting.com.

My approach would be, that i have a pre filled table with tags (in MySQL) and a user can just use these tags. But this is not scaleable.

How can i make that scaleable? I'm worried if i let the users just create tags, that the system gets cluttered (typos for example).
What is a good approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "submit tag for approval" / "Request tag to be added" option which you can then approve and it will add it to the list in your table

The submitted entries can be stored in a table and when you approve them it can be removed from the holding table and moved into your "Valid" list of tags

Once it is approved you could also get the id of the entry you created and append that back to the list of tag id's that the user has associated.

If the tag is rejected you could provide a reason (also stored in a table i.e. duplicate, erroneous data etc) this could be sent to the requester via push messages or email however you are able to communicate it back to the user.

Comment: I think thats a great idea. And in the beginning i just pre fill the database. Do you have a good resource for job related tags? (might be a bit specific tough) ;)

Comment: Hey.. Not at present. But I think Linked-in has a API that you can call to... Correction they removed it

Comment: Bit of manual work but you could use this as a start https://www.linkedin.com/directory/topics/